# How to import modules in Paver?

Tags: python, paver

I am using Paver for the first time and I can't import in my pavement.py a module I created in the same directory. The module was working when imported in a standalone script in the same directory. I guess paver is running from somewhere else, not the same directory.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

After a bit of investigation I found a solution...

```
import sys
sys.path.append( os.path.abspath('.') )
import mymodule.myscript as myscript
```

Comment: I'd say cwd should not be touched, would You consider opening a bug for this?